# Can I use this Dirac delta distribution identity to evaluate this integral?

Tags: dirac-delta

I know of the identity $\int dy \delta(x-y)\delta(y-x') = \delta(x-x')$ but what about if I have an integral like $$\int dy \delta(x-y)\delta(y-x')f(y)$$Can the above identity be used in any way? Can say something like this?$$\int dx\int dy\delta(x-y)\delta(y-x')f(y) = \int dx \delta(x-x')f(x)$$

Comment: Intuitively that should equal $f(x)\delta(x-x')$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can think of integrals with delta functions as this: the integral will only not be zero at x=x‘. You can plug the function g(x)=1 into the identity you listet and the result is g(x‘)* delta(x-x‘)=delta(x-x‘). Applying this to the second integral gives the result f(x‘)*delta(x-x‘)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? I don't follow at all. Where do you "plug $g=1$"? And how does this prove the formula for an arbitrary $f$?